# Forbidden Attribute Error params ruby search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having an isuue.  I am creating a search form in my form.  The form has restaurant name, city, and state.

Looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag(restaurants_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:restaurant_name) %> 
    <%= text_field_tag :restaurant_name, params[:restaurant_name]  %> <br />
    <%= label_tag(:city, "Restaurant City") %> 
    <%= text_field_tag :city, params[:city] %> <br />
    <%= label_tag(:state, "Restaurant State") %>
    <%= text_field_tag :state, params[:state] %> <br />
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Now I am trying to get information for a part restaurant name/location.

I have seen that if my form is coded properly, which it is you can do something like:

```
Restaurant Controller:
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_restaurant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :search]

  # GET /restaurants
  # GET /restaurants.json
  def index
    constraints = Hash.new
    constraints[:restaurant_name] = params[:restaurant_name] 
    constraints[:city] = params[:city]

    if params[:restaurant_name] && params[:city]
    #@restaurants = Restaurant.search(params[:restaurant_name]).order('restaurant_name desc').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
        @restaurants = Restaurant.where(params).order('restaurant_name desc').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    else
        @restaurants  = Restaurant.order('restaurant_name desc').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])

    end
  end

  # GET /restaurants/1
  # GET /restaurants/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /restaurants/new
  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new
  end

  # GET /restaurants/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /restaurants
  # POST /restaurants.json
  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @restaurant.save!
    session[:page] = 0
        format.html { redirect_to restaurants_url, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # GET /restaurants/1/search
  # GET /restaurants/1.json
  def gotosearch



  end

 def self.search

        Restaurant.where("restaurant_name like ? AND city like ? ", params[:restaurant_name], params[:city]) 


    end

  # PATCH/PUT /restaurants/1
  # PATCH/PUT /restaurants/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @restaurant.update(restaurant_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @restaurant }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end



  # DELETE /restaurants/1
  # DELETE /restaurants/1.json
  def destroy
    @restaurant.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to restaurants_url, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end




  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_restaurant
      @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def restaurant_params
      params.require(:restaurant).permit(:restaurant_name, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :split_the_check, :dont_split_the_check)
    end

end
```

Comment: What version of Rails is your app, and can you post your restaurants_controller?

Comment: 4.  I will post it right now.

Comment: I first did it without constraint hash

Comment: Now can you post any routes having to do with restaurants?

Comment: Only thing I have is this:

Comment: resources :restaurants
I am pretty much creating a form and doing the main work in the index

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
@restaurants = Restaurant.where(params).order('restaurant_name desc').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
```

You are searching with a variable called params, which holds all the parameters for the request. You need to do something more specific like this:

```
@restaurants = Restaurant.where(params[:restaurant_name]).order('restaurant_name desc').paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
```

Or you can search by constraints[:restaurant_name] since you're already declaring that variable.

And if you're searching based on multiple attributes you can do this:

```
@restaurants = Restautanr.where("restaurant_name = ? OR name = ? OR state = ?", params[:restaurant_name], params[:city], params[:state])
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  But question.   I have 3 parameters.  So if I type in any of the 3 fields (restaurant name, city, state) results should pop up.  how can I do this?